# My Logger object is sending two messages instead of one

Tags: python-2.7, logging, handler, message

I'm trying to create a Logger object which can log info to my console without having the root name.

```
# Set up logger.
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s:%(message)s"))
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    logger.info("test")
```

Returns two logging messages: the correct one set up by handler and the original if i hadn't added a handler, what's the issue?

```
INFO:root:test
INFO:test
```

After messing around with it, I'm finding that this only occurs if a) I am adding the handler or b) I import another module with a logger.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you've missed

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

before doing logging, you just set for your handler
without this, I could not get any output

and since you got two output, maybe you got other files that also create an logger ?